# Windows 10 Network Share External Drive to Android

Tags: networking, windows-10, permissions, android, network-shares

C:\ Shares can be accessed while D:\ Shares give network errors on Android devices and thus cannot be accessed. (but they do work on windows clients without login) Is there any logging/feedback I can access to find what the problem is ?

**Important info:** Ownership & Permissions have been changed on the drive in the past, but have been set back to SYSTEM.

**Folder on C:\ (NVME SSD)**

- Folder Permissions: Everyone \ Full Control
- Share Permissions: Everyone \ Full Control
- Owner: Me (Microsoft Account)

**Folder on D:\ (EXTERNAL HDD)**

- Folder Permissions: Everyone \ Full Control
- Share Permissions: Everyone \ Full Control
- Owner: Me (Microsoft Account)

**Network Settings:**

- Network is Private
- Network discovery is turned on
- File & printer Sharing is turned on
- Use user accounts and passwords to connect to other computers
- Password protected sharing is turned off

Comment: Every permission youmliseted is only respected by Windows clients Android doesn't understand Windows permission by default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To awnser my own question:

To view networking errors you can use the Windows Event Viewer:

> Start > Event Viewer > Windows Logs > System

There I found out that "srv" was spewing errors when I wanted to access the share:

> "The server's configuration parameter "irpstacksize" is too small for
>   the server...blabla"

Additionally when using some android file managers they actually present you with an error code instead of giving a generic "network error". In my case it was **error 0xC0000205**

**SOLUTION**

Open Regedit and go to

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Systen\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters

Add or set "IRPStackSize" (case sensitive) to a higher number

(decimal range 11 - 50, default == 15)

Reboot or manage to restart all Lanman related services & PRESTO, working android accessible shares !

Comment: Nice find. Good self answer